# Is it possible to use Maven instead of Gradle in Android?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I want to remove gradle completely from my app, and start using Maven. I know that Gradle is the official and default way, but due to some restrictions, I need Maven. I have investigated but did not come up with a solution. Is is possible? How?

In case that it is possible, how can you set the different parameters? e.g. multiDexEnable, compileSdkVersion, buildTypes...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Android Maven Plugin](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/)

> The Android Maven Plugin is used to build applications for the Android operating system as well as build libraries to be used in these efforts in AAR and the legacy APKLIB format using Apache Maven.

It seems quite updated and there's also a [GitHub](https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin) page. Beside, some [examples](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/examples.html) will help you setup your project.